# How to trace out all messages sent to a particular class or instance in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, uikit, introspection

I would like to trace out all messages sent by the Objective-C runtime to a particular class, say UITableView (or a particular instance) so I can better understand the inner workings of some classes.  Is there a way to do this?

Another use case is to trace out all delegate methods that are being called (say UITableViewDelegate methods) without having to declare them and put a trace method in each of them.

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little heavy-handed, but try setting the `NSObjCMessageLoggingEnabled` environment variable to `YES`. That will show *all* the messages sent to *every* object, but you can easily filter it down to the messages sent to a particular class.

Some good tips here: http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2006/04/22/tracing_objc/

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if the environment variable works for iPhone.